# How to find out which implementation slf4j is using

Tags: java, logging, pom.xml, slf4j

I am using slf4j, and it is logging, but it is not using logback as it's supposed to (since changes within the logback(-test).xml do not affect logging behaviour.

```
This is my POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.goodgamestudios</groupId>
    <artifactId>Icosphere</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Icosphere Data Platform</name>
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.arquillian_core>1.1.8.Final</version.arquillian_core>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.arquillian_core}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprfs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2-mapr</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprfs-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-mapr-2.1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.94.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cloudera.htrace</groupId>
            <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.05</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby.joni</groupId>
            <artifactId>joni</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-ejb_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-weld</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
            <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>mapr-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>secondPartTestsExecution</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-wildfly-remote</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.14.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <arquillian.launch>arquillian-wildfly-remote</arquillian.launch>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Additionally I removed all the indirect references to any logging library (common & log4j) which were present, and since did not provide the slf4j-simple lib, it can't fallback to that, either. Ist there some way to find out what it is using?

Thanks!

Comment: It logs it out on DEBUG level (or writes WARNs if there is no backend loaded)

Comment: Check to make sure that you don't have an additional logback configuration file somewhere on your classpath. Sometimes the logback jar contains a config file which gets picked up first, causing yours to be ignored.

Comment: Even if I take the logback jars out of the pom it still compiles and logs as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that when I am using an application server (which I did, Wildfly), the whole logging-configuration etc. is done on serverside, not on applicationside. In my case:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration